# How do I clear the input values in a react form?

Tags: forms, reactjs, firebase, input

In my code I have mention preventDefault method on onSubmit event and due to that my page is not getting reload when user enter data in form...

Can you tell me any way by which I can export data to firebase and also reload my page automatically!

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const firebase = require('firebase');
const uuid = require('uuid');

var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAtpOSiCqFy43ZTE-7CJdcHrIGNN1GrsSk",
  authDomain: "electronic-health-record-a795c.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://electronic-health-record-a795c.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "electronic-health-record-a795c",
  storageBucket: "electronic-health-record-a795c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "545743770560"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
class Usurvey extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uid: uuid.v1(),
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
    };
    this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
    this.inputData = this.inputData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
      .on('value', snap => console.log('from db', snap.val()));
  }

  submitData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
      .set({
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName,
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  inputData(event) {
    const firstName = this.refs.name1.value;
    const lastName = this.refs.name2.value;
    this.setState({ firstName, lastName });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.inputData} ref="name1" />
          <input type="text" onChange={this.inputData} ref="name2" />
          <input type="submit" />Submit
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Usurvey;
```

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page in the first place, the entire concept of SPA is doing stuff without reloading the page.

Comment: Then how one user entered details and comes to that page again?

Comment: you should reset your form on submission that way user can input more information if he/she want. Also the refs method you are using is not the best way to change form. You should update your state but not like this.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find best documentation? And I’m newbie in reactjs, so such problems are arising with me! I hope you get my confusion!

Comment: have a look at my answer.

Comment: Yes I got it completely, I read about such thing but I can’t able to relate it over here by myself. Thanks for generous help....  It’s very helpful if you help me to find good documentation...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164888/discussion-between-yash-choksi-and-adeel-imran).

Comment: I implemented your approach but it won't make the fields blank, the values are there only.

Comment: I have updated my answer, have a look at it.

Comment: @YashChoksi You sent me a link to answer this question. You have several answers, you even accepted one of the answers. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't think jsrbn's location.reload() approach is a good way of solving this problem. If you store other values in state, forcing the page to reload will clean out any built up state you might need. If you want to clear the inputs then resetting the input values like Adeel explains is a much better approach. If you don't want to clear out the inputs then you need to explain to us why you want to reload the page. Refreshing the page is not something you usually do in a single page application. One of the advantages of using something like react is not having to reload the page constantly.

Comment: Yeah I gone with Adeel's approach and which you just mentioned, but by applying this given code still I can't able to clear the fields.

Comment: It looks fine, give me some time and I'll run it and see if I find any problems. what errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: actually no error but shows something like this.....

Comment: {uid: "ff6540c0-0e92-11e8-8f5f-a5f26b2d2f40", firstName: "yash", lastName: "dlskjf"}
VM316 .lp:5 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Looks like Adeel figured out the problem. Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, it works completely. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it should be

```
 class Usurvey extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uid: uuid.v1(),
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
    };
    this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
    this.inputData = this.inputData.bind(this);
  }

   componentDidMount() {
     firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
      .on('value', snap => console.log('from db', snap.val()));
   }

   submitData(e) {
    const { firstName, lastName } = this.state;
    e.preventDefault();
    firebase
     .database()
     .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
     .set({
       firstName: firstName,
       lastName: lastName,
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error));

      this.setState({
        firstName: '', lastName: ''
      });
   }

   inputData(e) {
     this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <form onSubmit={this.submitData}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.inputData} name="firstName" />
          <input type="text" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.inputData} name="lastName" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
        </div>
     );
   }
}
export default Usurvey;
```

You directly update your state as the user inputs in the form, also on your submission you reset your form, so the user can add more information in the form.

Comment: const { firstName, lastName } this.state;

above line shows error.....!

Comment: that was a typo i have fixed it.

Comment: I tried your solution but still on submit the fields aren't blank they retain their values.

Comment: Oh my bad! I am sorry the problem was in the `<input />` field. I was not giving it the value field and bind that prop to that component state. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload your data and reload after it has finished you can do sth like this:

```
submitData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`Newdata/${this.state.uid}`)
      .set({
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName,
      })
      .then(() => {
        location.reload();
        // or window.location.reload() if location is undefined
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Comment: I don't like this approach, but if `location.reload()` doesn't work. Then this will `window.location.reload()` Don't use `this`  with it.

Comment: fixed it, sorry